# Is there a programmatic way or standard way to disconnect someone from a router?

Tags: networking, wifi

I've got an application where I need to allow users to connect to a WiFi router that is not connected to the internet, interact with something for 5-10 minutes and then disconnect. Since the router's AP can only handle a certain number of users, if the user doesn't disconnect from the router they end up preventing other users from connecting to the system.

So, I'd like to kick them off the router when they're done with the system.

To paint a clearer picture, imagine this is a guided tour at a museum. When they're done with the tour it would be great if I could disconnect them. Otherwise they might just put their phone in their pocket and sit in the cafe for an hour using up an AP slot while other guests go without. I suspect most users will switch off the museum's WiFi anyway because the WiFi for the tour has no internet but it still got me curious if I could kick them off. Maybe also record their MAC address so they can't get back on for a minute or 2 so that their phone will likely switch over to the cafe's WiFi with internet rather than just reconnect to the museum's

Other than low-level programming my own router AP from scratch is there any standard way to do this? Some protocol or specific brand or firmware for a particular router that would provide a programatic way to do this?

Of course I can run my own DHCP server easily but killing their IP address on DHCP won't, as far I know, disconnect them at a lower level from the router's AP.

Comment: This is going to depend on the AP in question; however, most APs offer a mac-address filtering function.  Your best bet (IMHO) is filtering the macs you want to disconnect for some period of time (perhaps an hour or so).

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be addressed from several angles:

- From the AP side. 
  If your router supports Guest networks with time limitation, this can be the easiest and most straightforward mean of achieving what you need - just go to the router settings and configure.
- From the client side. 
  Depending on your OS, you have a set of APIs to control the connection. You can utilize these APIs in your application and just disconnect the link when a user exceeds its time limit.
- Use proxy. Search the internet for proxy SW, time limitation setting might be included in its capabilities (think of the common usecase of connecting to a public hot spot where you need authorization - there is a proxy in the background that controls what and you can do with your connection. Actually, this resembles very much your own usecase).

Answer (score -1):

Wifi router has DHCP server inside for providing IP addresses to wireless clients. Setting up lease time of DHCP server on router may be one of standard.

If your users interact 5-10 minutes in usual, setting 20-30 minuts for default-lease-time may be enough.

If your users interact upto 1-2 hours, setting 3 hours for maximum-lease-time may be enough.

Lease time is automatically added upto maximum-lease-time for users who has connection, Long-time users may not notice that their connection is disconnected.

Comment: I could be wrong but AFAIK DHCP is at a higher level than the Access Point system. So, dis-allowing DHCP won't actually disconnect the phone from the router. It will just not provide an IP address.  I believe I need to disconnect below DHCP's level at the data link level (level 1?)

Comment: @gman You're mostly correct. You indeed need to disconnect at data link layer (it's level 2)